# Upload large files to server in android?

Tags: android, file-upload

I am using the following example to upload video to server.

[UPLOAD AUDIO VIDEO IMAGE](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/29/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/)

However I am not able to upload large size video files say more than 2 MB.

Any other example would help me if possible?
Or is there need to be any change in the above code?

Comment: Check once in your server side. What is the maximum file size supported

Comment: There is no limit given on the server side for upload...in the link I provided the server side PHP script is given...please check that if any changes need to be done in that

Answer (score 2):

The limit is not set in your PHP script, but in the global server settings. If you have access to php.ini, check the values for **upload_max_filesize** and **post_max_size**. You will need to restart Apache after updating php.ini.

If you don't have access to php.ini (e.g. shared hosting) and the host allows it, you can try setting the limits writing something like this in your .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

You can check the server settings using the phpinfo() function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.[tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

Through this code you can upload files upto 10mb.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should try android:largeheap="true" in manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```